# onChange event is not triggering in jQuery / Ajax form submission

Tags: javascript, ajax

**Form submission using Type and Action methods**

onChange event is working fine with this method in both Firefox and Chrome.

```
<form name="frmname" action="./add_p.php" method="POST">
    <div>
        <select name="cbo_name" id="cbo_name" onChange="dosomething();">
            <option value="USA">America</option>
            <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
            <option value="UK">England</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Form submission using jQuery / Ajax**

onChange event is not triggered in this method so I have used onClick event and it is working fine in both Firefox and Chrome.

```
<form name="frmname" id="frmname" novalidate>
    <div>
        <select name="cbo_name" id="cbo_name" onClick="dosomething();">
            <option value="USA">America</option>
            <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
            <option value="UK">England</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>


Ajax call on JS page

$.ajax({
.
.
})
```

Why is it behaving like this? I am curious to know this. Ty

Comment: is there any option tags ?

Comment: Its `onchange` instead of `onChange`..

Comment: Dont you have options?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, it doesn't make any difference whether we use onchange or onChange in both browsers...

Comment: @KAhir right.but 
 
is there any option tags

Comment: It will not work without option

Comment: @FastSnail, yes there are options but I just didn't mentioned to keep question as short as possible.

Comment: @KAhir cannot reproduce working perfectly https://jsfiddle.net/33do9k04/.
check browser console to see if there is any errors

Comment: @FastSnail, no error in browser console...

Comment: @KAhir can you show live example?jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

**You code is working fine with onChange. Below is your code which I have checked.**

```
<form name="frmname" id="frmname" novalidate>
    <div>
        <select name="cbo_name" id="cbo_name" onChange="dosomething(this.value);">
            <option value="USA">America</option>
            <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
            <option value="UK">England</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    function dosomething(value) {
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not working because of in select box you not using options.
for onchange options is required. you can check just adding in you code like.**

```
<form name="frmname" action="./add_p.php" method="POST">
    <div><select name="cbo_name" id="cbo_name" onChange="dosomething(this.value);">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select></div>
</form>
<script>
    function dosomething(value) {
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

**Let me know if you facing issue again.**

Answer (score 0):

try this :

(your html)

```
<form name="frmname" action="./add_p.php" method="POST">
    <div>
        <select name="cbo_name" id="cbo_name" >
            <option value="USA">America</option>
            <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
            <option value="UK">England</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

(js handler)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#cbo_name").change(function(e) {
        var cbo_nameValue = $(this).val();

        your.function.dosomething(cbo_nameValue);

    });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
<select name="cbo_name" id="cbo_name" onChange="dosomething()">
     <option value="USA">America</option>
        <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
        <option value="UK">England</option>
</select>
```

**No need of semicolon after function**

Comment: onchange and onChange both are giving same result in both browsers.

Comment: It will work try this on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onchange